# UniSharp/Laravel Filemanager saving data to database table

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

I am using Laravel file manager in my application so that users have a nicer experience when uploading files to my application.

**What I've done previously**

In previous setups, I've had a store method that takes the file path returned by the file manager and stored that in a database table with other items related to say, a news article or an event.

In these scenarios, the user would upload the image via the file manager and then select it, which would auto-fill a text field specifying the image path.

So in these scenarios I had a database like the following that was majoritively filled in by user input.

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('excerpt')->nullable();
    $table->mediumText('content')->nullable();
    $table->string('featuredImage')->nullable();
    $table->mediumText('featuredVideo')->nullable();
    $table->string('author')->nullable();
    $table->string('readingTime', 15)->nullable();
    $table->string('category')->nullable();
    $table->string('published')->default('pending');
    $table->boolean('featuredArticle')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Where `featuredImage` is a path created by the user after they had uploaded the image and selected it, returning a relative image path.

**What I'm attempting**

I have a scenario where users can add to an image/ documents library by uploading files to a particular folder using Laravel file manager, to display this in a list initially I did the following:

```
            @foreach ($fileList as $file) 

            @php 

            // UNIX timestamp
            $time = Storage::lastModified($file); 

            // Human readable date
            $date = gmdate("d/m/Y - H:i", $time); 

            // Filesize in Bytes
            $size = Storage::size($file);

            // Filesize converted to KB
            $size = ceil ($size/1000); 

            // URL to given file
            $url = Storage::url($file); 


            $fileName = pathinfo($file)['filename']; 

            $category = pathinfo($file)['dirname']; 

            $type = pathinfo($file)['extension']; 

            $category = basename(dirname($file))

            @endphp

            <tr>
                <td>{{$type}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $fileName }}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $size }}kb</td>
            </tr>


            @endforeach
```

As you can see, this just loops through a folder in storage and juts out info using a mix of PHP functions and the Storage Fascade.

**What I realised**

I came to the conclusion that this method was stupid as there's no way of maintaining or watching over the uploaded files as there was no related database table, so I made the following table:

```
Schema::create('file_meta_data', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('department')->nullable();
        $table->string('category')->nullable();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('size');
        $table->string('filepath');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

This way, as long as the path doesn't change, an admin can add the extra data regarding category and department via a form in the admin area, which will make it possible for me to categorise files even if the user uploads them with a silly name or something.

What I want to do is have it so when the user uploads a file to the storage folder via the file manager, a database record is created for that file.

I see in the documentation for the file manager, there are events you can listen for, but given the following link: https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager-demo-events, it seems that the package only has Event Listeners for when images are uploaded.

I tried the following as a rudimentary workaround.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\FileMetaData;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class TemplateController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $fileList = Storage::allFiles('files/shares');

        // Loop through the tag array that we just created
        foreach ($fileList as $files) {
            $file = FileMetaData::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'name' => basename($files),
                    'department' => basename(dirname($files)),
                    'category' => null,
                    'type' => Storage::mimeType($files),
                    'size' => Storage::size($files),
                    'filepath' => Storage::url($files)
                ]
            );
        }

        return view('pages.templates-and-tools.index', compact('fileList'));
    }
}
```

Essentially when a user goes to the page with the file list, the script checks to see if this file in storage has a database entry, otherwise it creates it.

This is rather poor, however, as if no one visits the page the folder and the database quickly go out of sync but the table is necessary to integrate searching for files via Elequent Models and queries.

To get around this would I have to create a new Event Listener that basically listens for any file type?